# How do I compile a static binary of Subsurface on MacOSX?

Tags: c, macos, static-libraries, autotools, ld

I am trying to make a static binary on [Subsurface](http://subsurface.hohndel.org/) on MacOSX, so that we can provide a simple binary download.  I'm clueless as to solve the problems I get, but that might just be because I suck at C.

Here's what I do.  I have already installed gconf and gtk2 from [MacPorts](http://macports.org), and I'm building without libusb for simplicity:

```
git clone git://libdivecomputer.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/libdivecomputer/libdivecomputer
cd libdivecomputer
autoreconf --install
./configure
make LDFLAGS="-static"
sudo make install
cd ..
git clone git://subsurface.hohndel.org/subsurface.git
cd subsurface
make LDFLAGS="-framework CoreFoundation -static"
```

The result is this:

```
gcc -framework CoreFoundation -static -o subsurface main.o dive.o profile.o info.o equipment.o divelist.o parse-xml.o save-xml.o libdivecomputer.o print.o uemis.o gtk-gui.o statistics.o macos.o  -L/opt/local/lib -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -liconv -lm -L/opt/local/lib -lxslt -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -liconv -lm -L/opt/local/lib -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lXext -lXrender -lXinerama -lXi -lXrandr -lXcursor -lXcomposite -lXdamage -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lXfixes -lcairo -lX11 -lpng14 -lpango-1.0 -lm -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl    /usr/local/lib/libdivecomputer.a  -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld_classic: can't locate file for: -lcrt0.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [subsurface] Error 1
```

Now, if I symlink /usr/lib/crt0.o to /usr/lib/crt1.o, I get this instead:

```
gcc -framework CoreFoundation -static -o subsurface main.o dive.o profile.o info.o equipment.o divelist.o parse-xml.o save-xml.o libdivecomputer.o print.o uemis.o gtk-gui.o statistics.o macos.o  -L/opt/local/lib -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -liconv -lm -L/opt/local/lib -lxslt -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -liconv -lm -L/opt/local/lib -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lXext -lXrender -lXinerama -lXi -lXrandr -lXcursor -lXcomposite -lXdamage -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lXfixes -lcairo -lX11 -lpng14 -lpango-1.0 -lm -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl    /usr/local/lib/libdivecomputer.a  -lpthread
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/libgcc_static.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libxml2.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libz.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/usr/lib/libpthread.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/usr/lib/libm.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libxslt.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libatk-1.0.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libXext.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libXrender.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libXinerama.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libXi.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libXrandr.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libXcursor.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libXcomposite.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libXdamage.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libgio-2.0.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libXfixes.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libcairo.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libX11.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libpng14.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libpango-1.0.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libfreetype.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libfontconfig.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libgobject-2.0.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libgmodule-2.0.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libgthread-2.0.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libglib-2.0.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/opt/local/lib/libintl.dylib) on link line
Assertion failed: (_pointerLocations.size() == 0), function size, file /SourceCache/ld64/ld64-123.2.1/src/ld/LinkEditClassic.hpp, line 961.
0  0x10226171c  __assert_rtn + 76
1  0x1023233f5  ld::tool::ExternalRelocationsAtom<x86_64>::size() const + 149
2  0x1022d8a17  ld::tool::OutputFile::updateLINKEDITAddresses(ld::Internal&) + 583
3  0x1022d1aae  ld::tool::OutputFile::write(ld::Internal&) + 142
4  0x102261caa  main + 1178
5  0x1022502b4  start + 52
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [subsurface] Error 1
```

And if I build libdivecomputer and subsurface with "-arch i686" instead, I get this:

```
gcc -framework CoreFoundation -arch i686 -static -o subsurface main.o dive.o profile.o info.o equipment.o divelist.o parse-xml.o save-xml.o libdivecomputer.o print.o uemis.o gtk-gui.o statistics.o macos.o  -L/opt/local/lib -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -liconv -lm -L/opt/local/lib -lxslt -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -liconv -lm -L/opt/local/lib -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lXext -lXrender -lXinerama -lXi -lXrandr -lXcursor -lXcomposite -lXdamage -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lXfixes -lcairo -lX11 -lpng14 -lpango-1.0 -lm -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl    /usr/local/lib/libdivecomputer.a  -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld_classic: /usr/lib/crt0.o incompatible, file contains unsupported type of section 2 (__IMPORT,__pointers) in load command 0 (must specify "-dynamic" to be used)
/usr/bin/ld_classic: incompatible flag -framework used (must specify "-dynamic" to be used)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [subsurface] Error 1
```

I'm on MacOSX Lion with XCode 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was not to build this thing statically, but to include the libraries in the .app bundle.  Both the binary and the library needed to be updated with [install_name_tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/install_name_tool.1.html) to use relative paths:

```
$ otool -L subsurface
subsurface:
    /opt/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.8.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.7)
    ...
$ install_name_tool -change /opt/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib \
  @executable_path/../Resources/lib/libxml2.2.dylib subsurface
$ otool -L subsurface
subsurface:
    @executable_path/../lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.8.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.7)
    ...
```

[gtk-mac-bundler](https://live.gnome.org/GTK+/OSX/Bundling) can be used to automate this process.  More details in the [Subsurface macosx packaging directory](https://github.com/torvalds/subsurface/tree/master/packaging/macosx).

Answer (score 0):

Unless the gtk libraries have `.la` (libtool) meta-files, and `.a` (static) builds, I don't know if this can be done easily - or at least automatically. At a minimum, add: `--disable-shared` to `./configure`

Could try: `env LDFLAGS="-static-libtool-libs" ./configure --disable-shared`, instead of setting it in the `make` invocation.

There's no point trying to link `CoreFoundation`, `libgcc`, etc., as static libraries, even if they exist, since they'll always be present.

Comment: Thanks for trying to figure this out! I added CoreFoundation since I need it to build Subsurface on this machine.  On my almost identical machine at work I don't need it, for whatever reason.  I tried configuring libdivecomputer the way you said, but it didn't help.  Subsurface doesn't have configure script.  And why does it look for the non-existing /usr/lib/crt0.o? Too many questions here :)

Comment: I am wondering if you found the reason of this problem? Thanks

Comment: @user454083 Nah, but I found a solution. See the accepted answer. :)